# Is there anything I can do about the poor quality of my PS2 games on a large TV?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, monitor, ps2

Last year when I moved from being a highschool student to a full-time web developer, I found myself with a never before seen abundance of money.

Of course the first thing I did was go out and purchase a 50" Plasma TV for my tiny room.

I also bought an XBOX 360, having before this only being able to afford a PS2.

The XBOX looks great (with a HDMI cable), but a couple of days ago I had an itch for playing through Final Fantasy X, XII and X-2. Unfortunately, the render quality on my new 50" TV doesn't look anywhere near as nice as it did on my old 65CM box TV that is now about 10 years old. I'm guessing this has something to do with stretching the game up so much.

Is there anything I can do about this aside from buying an older/smaller TV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you got a [component video cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MIXFWA) (that's the official Sony variant, but many generic ones are available for cheaper) for your PS2?  Most PS2s came with composite video cables (1 video and 2 audio outputs)  This cable has 3 video outputs and 2 audio outputs.  You can pick them up cheaply nowadays.

You can also edit the PS2's output format in its setup, which is easiest to access if you don't put a disc in the drive when you start up the PS2.  You can edit the various options there to try and get a better looking picture on the TV.  Most modern TVs also have options for dealing with lower resolution inputs, so you'll want to play with your TV options as well to ensure the best picture possible.

Only certain games support [HD output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_2_games_with_HD_support), so you may have to live with SD quality on certain titles, and others may require that you change the Playstation 2's setup before playing them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the suggested cable a try, assuming I can pick one up at JB or EB Games.

Comment: A handful of games support 1080i (most notably Gran Turismo 4) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_2_games_with_HD_support

Comment: You will probably have to adjust the settings per game to see what works. Some games will not work at all with 480p on component. :(

Comment: Good points guys.  Added some additional details.